# Strong convergence for time-dependent functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u=u(t,x)\in C(\mathbb{R},H^s(\mathbb{R}))$ and suppose that, as $t$ goes to infinity, we have the following weak convergence: $$
u(t,\cdot)\rightharpoonup u^*(x) \quad \hbox{in} \quad H^{s'}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $s'<s$ and "$\rightharpoonup$" denotes the weak convergence in $H^{s'}$. If we additionally assume that $u(t,\cdot)$ is uniformly bounded in $H^s$, say $$
u\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R},H^s(\mathbb{R})),
$$
does this imply that $u(t,\cdot)$ strongly converge to $u^*$ in $H^{s'}$? If we assume that $u^*$ belongs to $H^s$ (recall that $s'<s$), does the previous hypotheses imply strong convergence in $H^{r}$ for all $s'\leq r<s$? In other words, if we have a function is converging in a very weak topology, but this function is also uniformly bounded in a **stronger** topology, does that implies that the function is strongly converging in the topologies "in between" them (whenever "in between" has sense, like in this case). If not, is it possible to fix the previous statement or there is no hope no get any result of this type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; you need stronger assumptions to upgrade weak to strong convergence. (It's interesting to note that this "difficulty in upgrading" crops up in, for instance, solving nonlinear PDE, where weak convergence isn't enough.)

We can work in general $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Take for instance $\phi(x)$ a smooth bump function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $u(t, \cdot) = \phi(\cdot - tv)$ where $v$ is some fixed vector. So $u(t, \cdot)$ is just translating $\phi$, a sort of "gliding hump". It is standard that $u(t, \cdot) \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d) = H^0(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I believe this should hold for $H^s$, $s > 0$ also. However $u(t, \cdot)$ does not converge strongly to 0 in any $H^s$. Yet $u(t, \cdot)$ has the same $H^s$ norm for all $t$, so satisfies $u \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}; H^s(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Moreover the zero function is in $H^s$ for any $s$; so both of your additional assumptions are satisfied, yet convergence cannot be upgraded.